# org.apache.commons.codec Cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64, but Eclipse keeps telling me this import cannot be resolved, even though I've added the apache commons codec jar file to both the lib file of my project and also as an Eclipse plugin. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64` is a method. You import Types, like `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`.